# There is an issue with my validate($data) function that's causing the rest of the code to be dysfunctional

Tags: php, validation, authentication

I've been having an issue with my login.php file with the function causing issue.

Here's a snippet of the code to get some understanding. This is where the issue lies.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "db_conn.php";

function validate($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


$uname = validate($_POST['username']);
$pass = validate($_POST['password']);

if(empty($uname)) {
    header ("Location: index.php?error= Username is required");
    exit();
} else if(empty($pass)) {
    header ("Location: index.php?error= Password is required");
}
?>
```

For some reason, when I type in the username and password to login from my database, it directs me to the login.php or it directs me back to index.php, which is not what I want. When I went into the terminal to figure out the issue it says that line 15 ($uname = ) and 16 ($pass = ) are undefined due to the function validate($data) above, but it's not the function that's the problem, after doing debugging.

I'm still very new at php and I'm doing this for a graduate project.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Another question: Why are you using the validate() function at all? When I write similar code, I use the data `$_POST['username']` without converting.  In my eyes only `trim()` can be usefull.

Comment: @Wiimm if you don't mind explaining. I was following a tutorial.

Comment: The `function validate()` is a disaster - random string mutation without any understanding is not how to make database operations safe. Don't use this tutorial! See my profile if you want to see a tutorial where password handling and database operations are done correctly.